# XOR Boolean algebra, simplifying

Tags: digital

I am doing boolean algebra simplification and got the result of

```
(A.B) xor(C xor D)
```

Does

```
(A.B) xor (C xor D) = (A.B) xor C xor D ?
```

Comment: Why not make a truth table and see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `xor` operation corresponds to addition mod 2, where 0 <=> false and true <=> 1, so, yes, it is an associative operation. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or#Relation_to_modern_algebra